# How to create extended partition in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, partition, mbr

All, I am tring to create partition in the installation of Ubuntu.
As I knew.

> MBR partitioning scheme allows you to have up to 4 partitions on a
>   drive, one of those partitions can be an "extended partition", which
>   acts as a container for any number of "logical partitions". The
>   partitions which are not inside the extended partition are called
>   "primary partitions".

So my question is How can I create a `extended partition`? The only options I can see is `Primary` and `Logical`.

[image]

How can I make it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a "logical" partition then the tool will automatically create an extended partition for it and this will be reflected in the screen display after you create the logical partition.

This won't work if you've already created 4 primary partitions because the extended partition needs one of those slots, but as long as you've only created 1->3 primary partitions then it'll be automatic.